# Must "where" precede a noun referring to a location and not a state?

Tags: grammar

> He crashed the car into a wreck where the police inspected the debris.

I am assuming where is a pronoun here. The question is whether the word that precede where must be a location. From most examples, it seems that if it's a pronoun it must refer to a noun preceding it unless it's at the start of a sentence. Is this the case? Also, note that wreck refers to the state and not the location; hence, the question.

Comment: Are you sure? pron.
1.
a. At, to, or in a place in which: She moved to a city where jobs were more plentiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that "where" is a pronoun in this sentence, but it's still an odd sentence given, as you say, "wreck" is a condition or object and not a location.  Nevertheless by using "where" the pronoun stands for the *location* of the wreck,  and not the wreck itself.  It's hard to say whether or not it is *required*; rather it is a useful way to add meaning to a sentence with very few words.

As a counter-example, if the writer meant to focus on the object itself:

> He crashed the car into a wreck **that/which** the police inspected.

Another example of using "where" to imply *location*:

> She placed on the candles on the cake **where** the children were eagerly waiting.

Again, the phrasing is unusual and slightly awkward, but not necessarily *wrong*.  I would say it falls into the category of "creative writing" *where* the rules are generally relaxed.

Comment: Do you know any similar example from a renowned author? I am asking, because I am still unsure if it's allowed.

Comment: @puffofsmoke  I don't see why it wouldn't be "allowed".

Answer (score 1):

I believe where can also be a conjunction (a subordinating one). That seems to fit the usage in your sample sentence.

As for pronoun usage, the answer to your original question is no. Consider "This is where I play" or "Where are your keys?"