# Can I use the word "where" as a Subordinating Conjunction which is not referring to a place or location?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, academic-writing

I'm about to finish writing a thesis on technical topics. I'm contemplating, whether or not I'm using the word "where" correctly as a subordinating conjunction.

English is my second language.

Here are a couple of examples **taken from my thesis**. I'll appreciate your feedback regarding the correctness of these sentences, as well as general information/rules on the right usage of "where" in a sentence.

Example 1:

> Neglecting first its nonlinear effects, the fiber can be represented by means of its frequency response (here comes an equation with variables that have to be determined), where ω =2πf is the angular frequency in rad/s, α is the wavelength-dependent attenuation constant in Np/m, β ( ω ) is the phase constant in 1/m, and L is the length of the fiber (in m).

Example 2:

> The fibers can be roughly separated into two types, namely a multi-mode fiber and a single-mode fiber (SMF) [19], where the latter is considered in the remaining of this chapter.

Example 3:

> The phase response shows that the amount of dispersion depends both on the fiber length and the signal bandwidth, where the impact of CD grows linearly with the transmission length, but quadratically with the signal bandwidth.

Example 4:

> Fig. 2.2 shows the received signal on the complex plane for the three different scenarios, where the symbol transitions are illustrated in gray and the Baud-rate sampled constellation points in blue.

Example 5:

> The black dots denote the nodes of the network, and the blue lines are the connecting optical transmission links, where the investigated link path is highlighted in pink. (something tells me that in this case I should use "whereas" rather than "where"...).

Example 6:

> It is also possible to consider the equalization problem as an estimation problem, where the estimation error between the equalized and the transmitted sequence has to be minimized.

I've posted this question earlier in *English Language Usage* stack, since I was not sure where exactly to post it. I've found a very similar question [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194747/must-where-precede-a-noun-referring-to-a-location-and-not-a-state), but it gives only one example and the answers there do not give a concise rule... 
I hope that the varity of my examples would lead to a better discussion.

Comment: Although the *literal* sense of ***where*** relates to "physical location", it's widely used more "metaphorically" in contexts ***where*** the concept of "spatial coordinates" is meaningless (such as this very sentence). Note that in your example #5, ***where*** and ***whereas*** are both perfectly valid, but the choice makes a big difference to the *meaning*. If we had more context, it would be easy to see which one is "correct".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: thank you very much for your feedback. Can I understand indirectly that my examples above are valid?
Regarding example 5: It is a part of a caption of a figure that illustrates a model of Germany's terrestrial optical internet network. Out of all possible paths between the 15 given nodes I have chosen one path, and have highlighted it with the color pink. Is it sufficient context to see which word is the better choice?

Comment: Looking at it more closely, I'm pretty sure only ***where*** makes sense for your example #5. Where ***where*** means ***in this diagram context** [where there are black dots and blue lines, **and** stuff highlighted in pink]*. Note that ***whereas*** means ***on the other hand / although / despite*** (there's some kind of contrast between the statement *before* it, and the "contradictory" statement that follows).